# alert individual attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to identify each element by it's name attribute. Each element has the same class and will ultimately contain differing dynamic information.

For example I would want the following code to alert the individual element's name value:

html:

```
<p class="pexample" name="0">this is p #1</p>
<p class="pexample" name="1">this is p #2</p>
<p class="pexample" name="2">this is p #3</p>
```

jquery:

```
$('p').on('click', function() {
    if ($('p').attr('name') !== undefined) {
        alert($('p').attr('name'));
    }
})
```

Here is a jsfiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/XG7nd/1/

This code however only alerts the initial elements name value. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you want `if ($(this).attr('name')` instead of `$('p')`. The latter selects all the `p` elements on the page...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do:

```
$('p').on('click', function() {
   var name = $(this).attr('name');// `this` here refers to the current p you clicked on
   if (name ) {
        alert(name); 
    }
})
```

While doing `$('p').attr('name')` this will always give you the name of the first item in the collection.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xc5DG/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','p', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XG7nd/5/)

Comment: If statement isn't accurate. It should also use `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `$(this)`

```
$('p').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).attr('name') !== 'undefined') {
        alert($(this).attr('name'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because you are getting the `name` attribute for the first `<p>` on every click. You need to specify the one that the event originated from:

```
$('p').on('click', function() {
if ($(this).attr('name') !== undefined) {
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
}
})
```

Note, jQuery selectors return an array of matching elements. You must use the `this` keyword to get a handle on the element in the current context.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XG7nd/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

You keep looking for the `p` element even on `click`, so it'll select the first one it finds.

**What your code says:**

When `p` is clicked:

- Find a `p` element and alert its attribute.

---

**What you really want:**

When `p` is clicked:

- alert the *clicked element's* attribute

---

### Solution

Select the attribute of `this`, which is the clicked element.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XG7nd/4/)

### JavaScript

```
$('p').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('name') !== undefined) {
        alert($(this).attr('name'));
    }
})
```

Read more about the [***this* keyword**](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/).